# Multiple optional path prefix segments for Illuminate Routing

Tags: php, laravel, routes, amp-html

I'm implementing a multi-lingual (and also multi-user) website with AMP support. To achieve this, my URL structure is the following:

```
/{language?}/{amp?}/{page?}
```

For the home page (/), you can have this versions:

```
/
/nl
/en
/amp
/nl/amp
/en/amp
```

For another page, say /about, you can have this versions:

```
/about
/nl/about
/en/about
/amp/about
/nl/amp/about
/en/amp/about
```

I'm using the Illuminate Routing library.

Now I use 4 lines of code. The problem is not that it is not working, but that I don't like HOW I have solved it, because for every segment I want to add in the future, the number of lines increase exponential. For a prefix with 3 optional segments, I need 8 lines of code, and 4 optional segments need 16 lines, etc.

```
Route::group(["prefix"=>"/"],$ROUTES);
Route::group(["prefix"=>"/{lang?}","where"=>["lang"=>implode("|",$LANGS)]],$ROUTES);
Route::group(["prefix"=>"/{amp?}","where"=>["amp"=>"amp"]],$ROUTES);
Route::group(["prefix"=>"/{lang?}/{amp?}","where"=>["lang"=>implode("|",$LANGS),"amp"=>"amp"]],$ROUTES);
```

This 4 lines are working as they should work, but I want to see a solution with 1 line of code (or at least a few), where I can easily add a segment and where I don't have to copy all existing lines and than the new segment to all the new ones.